# MySQL 8 "mysql" binary not honouring "-p" to force a password prompt

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have an entry for 'joe'@'%' with the same password and the same mysql_native_password plugin on a MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8 server for these tests.

The "mysql" binary from MySQL 5.7 honours "-p" as expected when I want to connect as a general user:

```
# on the MySQL 5.7 localhost
$ mysql -u joe -h localhost -P 3306 -p
Enter password:

# on the MySQL 5.7 localhost to the MySQL 8 remote host
$ mysql -u joe -h remotehost -P 3306 -p
Enter password:
```

or as the root user defined in .my.cnf (which lets you connect without passed user/password information):

```
# on the MySQL 5.7 localhost using the root user defined in .my.cnf
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

but the "mysql" binary from MySQL 8 doesn't seem to honour "-p" and instead, immediately throws an error:

```
# on the MySQL 8 local host
$ mysql -u joe -h localhost -P 3306 -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'joe'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

# on the MySQL 8 local host to the MySQL 5.7 remote host
$ mysql -u joe -h remotehost -P 3306 -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'joe'@'remotehost' (using password: YES)
```

while as the root user defined in .my.cnf, it fails to honour but succeeds to connect:

```
# on the MySQL 8 local host using the root user defined in .my.cnf
$ mysql -u root -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
```

Putting the credentials for 'joe' into .my.cnf allows me to connect fine (confirming the password is good):

```
$ mysql -u joe -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
```

I'm puzzled and look forward to being embarrassed by a simple solution :)

**Workaround:** `mysql --no-defaults` will honour `-p`

Comment: Does it work if you use `-ppassword`? I know this isn't recommended, I just want to see if it works.

Comment: Do you have a `.mylogin.cnf` file? I think this may be overriding the command line option.

Comment: Try it with `-h 127.0.0.1` on both hosts.

Comment: @Barmar It *DOES* work with -ppassword ; this also proves the host and credentials are good.  There *IS* a .mylogin.cnf file on the MySQL 8 VM that I did not explicitly create (it is not on the MySQL 5.7 VM).  Moving that file to DOTmylogin.cnf doesn't fix the problem yet.  I'm going to take some time this morning to dig deeper...

Comment: For the record, .mylogin.cnf contained the root credentials, only visible with `my_print_defaults`; using `mysql_config_editor print --all` returned nothing.  That said, keeping or removing the file didn't seem to affect the behaviour when trying to use mysql with "-p"

Comment: I don't have an 8.x configuration here, so I can't test if I can reproduce this myself. @BillKarwin do you have an environment where you can test it?

Comment: @BillKarwin No difference using `-h 127.0.0.1` or IP name or `localhost`: MySQL 5.7 prompts for password (and successfully connects); MySQL 8 does not prompt for password (and immediately throws `Access denied`).

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on MySQL 8.0 in my environment. 
Do you set a password in your `~/.my.cnf`? If you do, then it uses that password, as if you had specified a password on the command-line. You could run `mysql --no-defaults` to make it skip reading the `.my.cnf` file.

Comment: `mysql --no-defaults -u joe -p` succeeds so there is this workaround (I'll edit the question with this).  It feels like this is a bug if MySQL 5.7 honours "-p" (regardless of ~/.my.cnf) but not MySQL 8 while the man page for using "-p" with mysql (still) states "If not given, mysql prompts for one."

Answer (score 0):

**This was a bug introduced in 8.0.29 and has been fixed in 8.0.31.**

Release Notes state "Following a bug fix in MySQL 8.0.29, if the password was provided in an option file, the mysql client did not prompt for a password if the -p option was specified at login. The client now always prompts for a password when the -p option is specified and uses the specified password, even if an alternative was populated from an option file. (Bug #107205, Bug #34134984)"

Although my scenario was from a different angle -- attempting to connect to a remote server with -u and -p -- the 8.0.31 client now offers a Password prompt as expected.

Answer (score -2):

error:ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'joe'@'localhost'
Check the user table, select host,user from mysql.user;

Comment: All seems good to me 
`$ mysql -e "select user,host from mysql.user where user='joe';"` returns
 `joe` and `localhost`.

Comment: It's supposed to ask for the password *before* it checks whether the user exists.